# codeigniter security extend not working, overwrite csrf_show_error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

CI Version: 2.2.0

I create a file at **/CI220/application/libraries/MY_Security.php**
config file I set

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

I found it didn't load the MY_Security, My MY_Controller is loading, but not this library. Below is my Call Stack Log:

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  242064  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.0009  244352  require_once( '/Users/User/Sites/CI220/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' )   ../index.php:202
3   0.0091  478200  load_class( )   ../CodeIgniter.php:213
4   0.0096  489872  CI_Input->__construct( )    ../Common.php:174
5   0.0097  491432  CI_Input->_sanitize_globals( )  ../Input.php:103
6   0.0232  499224  CI_Security->csrf_verify( ) ../Input.php:647
7   0.0233  499432  CI_Security->csrf_show_error( ) ../Security.php:149
```

I is not loading my extended library from Security. I want to overwrite the csrf_show_error function

```
public function csrf_show_error()
{
    show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.!!!');
}
```

Comment: In your `MY_Security.php` file do you have the `MY_Security` class correctly set-up? ie. `class MY_Security extends CI_Security {}`

Comment: Yes, I am set-up correctly.

Comment: libraries/MY_Security.php is wrong path
it must be in core folder > core/MY_Security.php

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer! That's make the tricks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Security** class is located in system/**core**/Security.php

The **Email** class is located in system/**libraries**/Email.php

You can refer to this link for core class:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Core classes are ALWAYS auto loaded, so you do not need to include in autoload also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Svetlio for the answer

libraries/MY_Security.php is wrong path it must be in core folder > core/MY_Security.php

I am having this confusion due to this page.
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

> **Extending Native Libraries**
>
> If all you need to do is add some functionality to an existing library
>   - perhaps add a function or two - then it's overkill to replace the entire library with your version. In this case it's better to simply
>   extend the class. Extending a class is nearly identical to replacing a
>   class with a couple exceptions:
>
> The class declaration must extend the parent class. Your new class
>   name and filename must be prefixed with MY_ (this item is
>   configurable. See below.). For example, to extend the native Email
>   class you'll create a file named application/**libraries**/MY_Email.php,
>   and declare your class with:.....

Thanks for the answer, so if you found that libraries folder not working can try for core folder.